# Lambda Projection of List<int> to SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I project the following list of integers and I will get my `SelectList`:

```
    public SelectList ContractOptions = new SelectList(new Proposals().ServiceByContracts.Select(x => (int)x.ContractLength).Distinct().ToList());
```

My results are:

```
Text Value
0    null
2    null
4    null
1    null
```

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

I need:

```
Text Value
0    0
2    2
4    4
1    1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public SelectList ContractOptions = new SelectList(
  new Proposals()
    .ServiceByContracts
    .Select(x => (int)x.ContractLength)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x=>new{Text=x.ContractLength.ToString(),Value=x.ContractLength.ToString()}),
  "Text","Value");
```

You could also try:

```
public SelectList ContractOptions = new SelectList(
  new Proposals()
    .ServiceByContracts
    .Select(x => x.ContractLength.ToString())
    .Distinct(),
  "ContractLength","ContractLength");
```

Comment: It's always better to have figured it out on your own.  You learn more that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way

```
IList<ServiceByContracts> serviceByContractList = new Proposals().ServiceByContracts.Select(x => (int)x.ContractLength).Distinct().ToList();
 public SelectList ContractOptions = new SelectList(serviceByContractList , "YourColumnIdName", "ColoumTextName");
```

**Update**

The `YourColumnIdName` means your ServiceByContracts table primary Key Id column Name and the `ColoumTextName` is your wanted ServiceByContracts table text column Name ...

Comment: this will crash at runtime with something like :`{"DataBinding: 'System.Int32' does not contain a property with the name 'YourColumnIdName'."}`

Comment: Hey that name means your ServiceByContracts table primary Key Id column Name and the ColoumTextName is your wanted ServiceByContracts table text column Name ...

Answer (score 0):

```
public SelectList ContractOptions = new SelectList(new Proposals().ServiceByContracts.Select(x => (int)x.ContractLength).Distinct().Select( d=>new {Text = d,Value =d}).ToList(),"Text","Value");
```

Ok .. I know Robert McKee has a similar approach, because I figured this out on my own.  I can to post my own answer!

To be a good sport i gave the answer to him!